# Csvkit how to stack many files

Tags: csv, stack, csvkit

I have about 1.5k csv files and I need to stack them. (OS: win10) 
How can i stack them using csvkit? (or maybe you can recommend something other that csvkit?)
I'm trying to the following. I created the [following structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJM1.png) and write

```
cd files
for /r %i in (*) do csvstack -e utf-8 ../res.csv %i > ../res.csv
```

But it doesnt really work. Help please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
csvstack *.csv >./output.csv
```

Comment: I am getting the output if I don't specify the output file name in terminal but getting an error if I specify the output file name. 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='csv1.csv' mode='rt' encoding='utf-8'>